# What is the advantage of using exponential function over trigonometric function in analyzing waves?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

A.P.French in his book **Vibrations and Waves** writes:

> . . . Why should the exponential function be such an important contribution to the analysis of vibrations? The prime reason is the special property of the exponential function. . .its reappearance after every operation of differentiation or integration.

Now,what is the advantage of using exponential function over trigonometric function? They are directly linked by De-Moiver's theorem.

Comment: I think you answered the question yourself.They are very easy to integrate and differentiate.

Comment: Related: [How can $F_0\cos\omega t$ change to $F_0e^{i\omega t}$ in driven oscillator equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227213/), and [What is the physical significance of the imaginary part when plane waves are represented as $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316135/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a gamble here from your age on your user page: we do have a [15 year old string theorist on this site (who is also from your homeland)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/23119/dimensio1n0), so at the risk of seeming belittling, here is something I found really satisfying in relation to your question when I was about your age.

Differentiation of trigonometric functions is fiddly. When you differentiate a $\sin$ it becomes a $\cos$, when you differentiate a $\cos$ it becomes a $-\sin$. So you have to differentiate *twice* to get a trigonometric function back to its original form. The *second* derivative $\mathrm{d}_t^2 f(\omega\,x)$ is equivalent to multiplying by $-\omega^2$ (where $f$ is any linear combination of $\sin\,\omega\,t$ and $\cos\,\omega\,t$), but the first derivative in general changes the function to something linearly independent from it.

In contrast, differentiation of $\exp(i\,\omega t)$ is equivalent to a simple *scaling*, which means it can greatly simplify operations containing derivatives of all orders, not just even ones, as is the case with $\sin$ or $\cos$.

This is all equivalent to saying that $\sin$ and $\cos$ fulfill second but not first order differential equations, whereas $e^{\pm i\,t}$, which are special linear combinations of $\sin$ and $\cos$ fulfill first order DEs. Here is a wonderful way of thinking that for me unified $e^{i\,t}$, $\sin t$, $\cos t$ and justified to me the complex number field when I was 17. We begin by thinking of the kinematics of something moving on a path around the unit circle. A position vector on this circle is  $\vec{r} = \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$ such that $\left<\vec{r},\,\vec{r}\right>=x^2+y^2=1$. We now find the equation of motion of a point $\vec{r}(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right)$ constrained to the circle is defined by ${\rm d}_t \left<\vec{r},\,\vec{r}\right> = 0$, whence $\left<{\rm d}_t \vec{r}(t),\,\vec{r}(t)\right> = 0$,  whence (with a little fiddling):

$${\rm d}_t \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right) = v(t) \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right)$$

where $v(t) = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}$. We take, for simplicity, $v(t) = 1$ so that we immediately have, by the universal convergence of the matrix exponential, when supposing that the the path begins at the point $x=1,y=0$ at time $t=0$:

$$\vec{r}(t) = \exp\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\,t\right]\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\mathrm{id} + i\,t + \frac{i^2\,t}{2!} + \frac{i^3\,t}{3!} + \cdots\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$$

where I have *defined*

$$i= \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$$

You can play around with this one and check that this $i$ has all the properties that the "everyday" $i$ has; in particular $i^2=-1$. Indeed, you can go a little further and prove that "numbers" of the form:

$$a \,\mathrm{id} + b\,i = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&-b\\b&a\end{array}\right)$$

add, subtract, multiply and divide exactly like the everyday complex numbers. The *field* of matrices of the form above is *isomorphic* to the complex number field. Mathematically it is therefore indistinguishable from the complex number field. Then we separate real parts (multipliers of the identity matrix) and imaginary parts (multipliers of the $i$ matrix to *define*, in this field:

$$e^{i\,t} = \cos(t) + \sin{t}\,i$$

and this entity has the useful property that its derivative is a simple scale factor times the original function and we get:

$$\cos(t) = \mathrm{id} - \frac{t^2}{2!}\mathrm{id}+ \frac{t^4}{4!}\mathrm{id} + \cdots$$
$$\sin(t) = \mathrm{id}\, t - \frac{t^3}{3!}\mathrm{id}+ \frac{t^5}{5!}\mathrm{id} + \cdots$$

How do these match up with everyday $\sin$ and $\cos$? Well, work out the co-ordinates of the point beginning at position $(1,0)$ and you will see that they are indeed given by the same $\sin$ and $\cos$ as defined above.

You may also enjoy the lecture by Richard Feynman:

["Algebra"; Lecture 22, Volume 1, The Feynman Lectures on Physics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html)

Comment: +1. Sir, I really do appreciate your effort. But I've to enhance my intellect so as to comprehend your valuable answer. I'll be learning Matrix within 3 months. So, I am waiting for reading your ans again:)

Comment: @user36790 Sorry, but be sure to come back and think about these things when you do. The matrix representation of the complex field is a really neat example.