# Choosing a Complex Trial Solution for a Forced Vibration Problem and Expressing The Driving Force in Complex Terms

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, harmonic-oscillator, vibrations

When solving forced vibration problems I would always choose a trial solution for the particular (stead-state) case in the form $x(t) = A \cos{\omega t} + B \sin{\omega t} $, but reading some books I got to know the complex form for the trial solution. At first I found it more intuitive, but after trying to use it I got some questions that I could not find  answers to.

Let us have a equation of motion of the form

$$ m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} + k x = F_0 \sin{\omega  t}$$

What is the difference of choosing a trial solution in the complex form $z = A~e^{i(wt-\phi)}$ and in the $z = A~e^{i(wt+\phi)}$. What should I expect from this change in the phase's sign? What is a more 'visual' interpretation of this change?

Also, when applying these complex forms, one usually has to change the harmonic excitation into a complex term too. The problem is: it seems that regardless of the excitation being a sine or cosine function, books always make

$$F_0 \sin{\omega t} \quad \text{or} \quad F_0 \cos{\omega t} \quad = \quad F_0~e^{i\omega t}$$

and, at the end, they just choose the imaginary or real part of the solution. Does it mean that $A$ and $\phi$ will not change despite we have a sine or cosine excitation?

Comment: You might try looking at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227213/how-can-f-0-cos-omega-t-change-to-f-0ei-omega-t-in-driven-oscillator-equa?rq=1

Comment: With the same boundary conditions,.nothing will change physically  $$\phi_{1} = -\phi_{2}$$

Comment: I actually checked this one before coming here. But still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this approach, the idea is to test a solution. It might not work, but with experience (and mathematical knowledge), you usually know where you're going of course.

When choosing a solution like $z(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$, you're choosing to look for a periodic, harmonic solution. Take note that $\omega$ is assumed to be positive at this point. It'll be important later.

That sort of solution lives in a 2-dimensional space, as can be seen with the presence of two free paramteters $A$ and $B$. In other words, you're trying to write the solution in the basis $(\cos(\omega t),\sin(\omega t))$.

As in any vector space, you're free to take linear combinations of elements, for example to change to another basis. Using for example:
$$\cos(\omega t)=\frac{e^{i\omega t}+e^{-i\omega t}}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sin(\omega t)=\frac{e^{i\omega t}-e^{-i\omega t}}{2i}$$
you can rewrite the solution in the basis $(e^{i\omega t},e^{-i\omega t})$:
$$z(t)=Ce^{i\omega t}+De^{-i\omega t}$$
Restarting from the first form of the solution, you can also rewrite as $z(t)=E\cos(\omega t+\varphi)$ or $z(t)=E\cos(\omega t-\varphi)$ with a bit of trigonometry.

When an author says that they're testing a solution like $e^{i\omega t}$, as long as $\omega$ is free to be positive or negative, they're going to get both terms written $e^{i\omega t}$ or $e^{-i\omega t}$ above. So they're also going to get both terms written as $\cos(\omega t)$ or $\sin(\omega t)$ above.

As for phase $\phi$, it's a phase shift between the excitation and the response. Depending on the sign you chose in the solution ($\omega t+\varphi$ or $\omega t-\varphi$) it'll be a delay or an advance in time.

Comment: I understand that when using trig. relations to $A$ and $B$, we can get $\cos{(\omega t + \phi)}$ or $\sin{(\omega t + \phi)}$. However, if I want to use the complex form, sometimes I get different answers depending on how I change the driving force into complex or if I choose a different trial solution (usually $\phi$ becomes $\arctan{A/B}$ or $\arctan{B/A}$). Maybe the answer is in geometric representation of this, but is kind of hard to see why all these answers are correct.

Comment: Since there are several different ways to parametrize the same physical problem, the safest way to handle it is to stick to a given choice and to avoid memorizing any formula. The exact definition for $\varphi$, and its precise physical interpretation, depend on this choice, so you should rebuild its expression in each case.

Comment: Thus I can choose to use $z(t) = A~e^{i(\omega t - \phi)}$ for the trial solution and $F(t) = F_0 \cos{\omega t}$ or $F(t) = F_0 \sin{\omega t}$ equal to $e^{i\omega t}$ and solve the equation of motion accordingly. Then, if the driving force is a sine function, I get the $Im$ part of the solution, if cosine, the $Re$ part? Further I could try to visualize it geometrically to get deeper understand on what these choices look like? Any source that you would recommend?

Comment: When you're using complex trial solutions, make sure that, where calculating their real part, you're falling back to their original, real expression. So $F_0\cos(\omega t)$ goes with $F_0e^{i\omega t}$, while $F_0\sin(\omega t)$ goes with $F_0e^{i(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})}=-iF_0e^{i\omega t}$.

Comment: For the equation of motion provided in the question, if I take $z = A~e^{i(\omega t - \phi)}$ and $F(t) = F_0\sin{(\omega t)} = F_0(-ie^{i\omega t})$, I get $\phi = \arctan{[ - (k-m\omega^2)/(c\omega)]}$, and the real part of $z$ is $A~\cos{(\omega t - \phi)}$. However, if I want $z$ with a sine for its real part, then I have to also change the trial solution $z$? Also, when I solve using the $A\cos{\omega t} + B \sin{\omega t}$, I get $\phi = \arctan{[c\omega/(k-m\omega^2)]}$. Why is it different? Or it is not?

Comment: I just followed your tips and the previous comments and I manage to come up with different solutions, depending on what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How you obtain the particular solution with complex ansatz

lets start with this equation:

$$ m \ddot{x} + c \dot{x} + k x = F_0 \cos{\omega  t}$$

or

$$ \ddot{x} + \delta \dot{x} + \omega_0^2 x = \frac{F_0}{m} \cos{\omega  t}\tag 1$$

we are looking for the particular solution $~x_p(t)~$

with
$$ \cos(\omega\,t)=\Re\left(e^{i\,\omega\,t}\right)$$

$\Rightarrow~$

$$\ddot{x}_p + \delta \dot{x}_p + \omega_0^2 x_p =\frac{F_0}{m}\,\,e^{i\,\omega\,t}\tag 2$$

to solve Eq. (2) you make the ansatz $~x_p(t)=A\,e^{i\,\omega\,t}$

thus Eq. (2)

$${{\rm e}^{i\omega\,t}} \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}+i\delta
\,\omega \right) A={\frac {F_0{{\rm e}^{i\omega\,t}}}{{m}^{2}}}\quad\Rightarrow\\
A={\frac {F_{{0}}}{{m}^{2} \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}+i
\delta\,\omega \right) }}
$$

and the solution
$$x_p(t)=\Re(A\,e^{i\,\omega\,t})={\frac {F_{{0}} \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) \cos
 \left( \omega\,t \right) }{{m}^{2} \left(  \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{
\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) ^{2}+{\delta}^{2}{\omega}^{2} \right) }}+{
\frac {F_{{0}}\delta\,\omega\,\sin \left( \omega\,t \right) }{{m}^{2}
 \left(  \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) ^{2}+{\delta}
^{2}{\omega}^{2} \right) }}
$$

and if the RHS is $~\frac {F_0}{M}\,\sin(\omega\,t)~$ then

with
$$ \sin(\omega\,t)=\Re\left(-i\,e^{i\,\omega\,t}\right)$$

you obtain the particular solution

$$x_p(t)=\Re(-A\,i\,e^{i\,\omega\,t})=
-{\frac {F_{{0}}\delta\,\omega\,\cos \left( \omega\,t \right) }{{m}^{2
} \left(  \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) ^{2}+{\delta
}^{2}{\omega}^{2} \right) }}+{\frac {F_{{0}} \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{
\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) \sin \left( \omega\,t \right) }{{m}^{2}
 \left(  \left( -{\omega}^{2}+{\omega_{{0}}}^{2} \right) ^{2}+{\delta}
^{2}{\omega}^{2} \right) }}
$$