# What are the physics behinde reflection and refraction of electromagnetic wave at a dialectric surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, reflection, refraction

I have understood the most of the equations that lead to the Fresnel-Equations from electromagnetic waves and Maxwell equations. But not enough to understand what is happening. So I don't ask for an answer under what circumstances, what equations lead to which results, but what physically is happening.

What at a surface leads a electromagnetic wave to reflect and transmit.

My first intuition was that if the electric field acts on the surface both materials get polarized by a different amount leading to a charge at the interface. The change of the electric field leads to a change of that charge and the interface is acting like dipole generating electromagnetic waves.
Then a s-polarised plane wave so where the electric field is perpendicular to the plane of incident and so parallel to the interface would not lead to any reflection. Except now the magnetic field is leading to some dipole. But in the Equations it dose.

I am happy for any ideas of misunderstanding, theories that explain the behavior not just by deriving the equations from Maxwell equations. Feynman dose say something about a current in the material of the transmitted wave, [Lecture I-33-6](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_33.html).
I also saw this [Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506973/simple-nonmathematical-argument-for-partial-polarization-by-reflection) that look similar to mine. Unfortunately, I can't get the paper mentioned there.