# Real and imaginary part of the solution to the Laplace Equation violates uniqueness?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve for the magnetic vector potential on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have used the phasor formulation of Maxwell's equations and therefore I believe I am solving the equation on $\mathbb{C}^2$. The equation I have derived is $$\nabla^2\hat{A}(r,\phi)=-\frac{\mu_0}{r}\delta(r-r')\delta(\phi-\phi')$$ where $\hat{A}(r,\phi)$ is the complex magnitude of the solution $A(r,\phi)=\Re({\hat{A}(r,\phi)e^{j \omega t}})$.

I believe that the transformation to phasor form is mostly a mathematical convenience and that it should have no effect on my final solution. However, when I have a solution $\hat{A}(r,\phi)$ that satisfies the Poisson equation and Dirichlet boundary conditions ($\hat{A}(r\to \infty,\phi)=0$), I will then have two real solutions namely $A_1(r,\phi)=\frac{\hat{A}e^{j \omega t}+\hat{A}^*e^{-j \omega t}}{2}=\Re({\hat{A}(r,\phi)e^{j \omega t}})$ and $A_2(r,\phi)=\frac{\hat{A}e^{j \omega t}-\hat{A}^*e^{-j \omega t}}{2 j}=\Im({\hat{A}(r,\phi)e^{j \omega t}})$.

My difficulty is in choosing which one of these is the "correct" solution (i.e. why I should choose one and disregard the other). And also why this doesn't violate the uniqueness of the Laplace equation with Dirichet boundary conditions.
My understanding is that if I solve the Poisson equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions then I am guaranteed a unique solution (See [Wiki: Uniqueness Theorem for Poisson Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation)).

Comment: If you're trying to solve Laplace's equation on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and your only boundary condition is $\hat{A}(r\to \infty,\phi)=0$, then the solution is $\hat{A} = 0$ everywhere and so $\Re \hat{A} = \Im \hat{A} = 0$ everywhere and the issue is moot.  I *assume* that the real problem you're asking about is more complicated than this, but I can't tell how; can you [edit] your question to include why you don't expect a zero potential everywhere?

Comment: Also, I would have assumed that you'd be solving the Helmholtz equation if you have a time-varying potential, not the Laplace equation.  But perhaps you have a different sort of setup in mind than the ones I'm used to.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My apologies, I have a single current source in the form of a delta function - this is a serious oversight on my part as it is rather the Poisson equation, I will edit the question, appropriately.

Comment: What's the full $t$-dependent equation that you're trying to solve?  Something like $\nabla^2 A(r,\phi,t)=-\mu_0 J(r,\phi,t)$?  It will make a difference for the answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The full equation is $\nabla^2 A(r,\phi,t)=-\frac{\mu_0}{r}\delta(r-r')\delta(\phi-\phi')\cos(\omega t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're presumably looking to solve the (real) equation
$$
\nabla^2 A(r,\phi,t)=-\mu_0 J(r,\phi,t)
$$
and have chosen a source of the form $J(r, \phi, t) = \frac{1}{r}\delta(r-r')\delta(\phi-\phi') \cos( \omega t)$.  When you go to the complex domain, you have implicitly replaced $\Re (e^{i \omega t})$ in the "real source" with $e^{i \omega t}$ as a "complex source";  and so when you solve the problem and want to find the "real potential" from the "complex potential", you have to undo this step.  In other words, if $J(r, \phi)e^{i \omega t}$ really stands for $\Re (J(r, \phi)e^{i \omega t} )$, then $\hat{A}(r, \phi)e^{i \omega t}$ really stands for $\Re (\hat{A}(r, \phi)e^{i \omega t} )$.

To see this more formally, consider the solutions to two real equations:
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 A_r(r,\phi,t)&=-\mu_0 J(r,\phi) \cos \omega t \tag{1} \\
\nabla^2 A_i(r,\phi,t)&=-\mu_0 J(r,\phi) \sin \omega t \tag{2}
\end{align}
The complex function $A_c(r, \phi, t) \equiv A_r + i A_i$ will then satisfy (by linearity)
$$
\nabla^2 A_c(r,\phi,t)=-\mu_0 J(r,\phi) e^{i \omega t} \tag{3}
$$
So one way to solve both (1) and (2) above is to solve (3) for $A_c$, and then take the real and imaginary parts of $A_c$.  The real part of $A_c$ gives the response to the real part of the source, and the imaginary part of $A_c$ gives the response to the imaginary part of the source.  (In typical situations we're not interested in this latter response, but it's still a valid solution to Poisson's equation for that source.)

See [this excellent answer from Emilio Pisanty](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/316143/81133) for more perspective on this last paragraph.

Comment: That's exactly the distinction I was missing, thank you for the great answer!