# Wave amplitude as a complex number?

Tags: wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers

In section **1-3 An experiment with waves** of *The Feynman Lectures on Physics* (https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html) it says:

*"The instantaneous height of the water wave at the detector for the wave from hole 1 can be written as (the real part of) ${h_1}e^{iωt}$, where the “amplitude” $h_1$ is, in general, a complex number."*

What does it mean to have a amplitude that is a complex number? I'm used to working with the wave representation of $Ae^{iwt}$ where $A$ is just a constant describing the amplitude, so I'm a bit lost when this amplitude all of a sudden is a complex number.

Comment: Buddy, as @mike stone has answered, a complex amplitude would be a complex number constant $h = a + ib$. Normally we are used to $b=0$ but the case $b≠0$ phase shifts the waveform by $\arctan (b/a)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the physical significance of the imaginary part when plane waves are represented as $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316135/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-the-imaginary-part-when-plane-waves-are-rep)  (That question deals with waves rather than oscillations, but Emilio Pisanty's answer still applies.)

Answer (score 6):

If $h= |h|e^{i\theta}$ then $he^{i\omega t}= |h|e^{i(\omega t +\theta)}$, so the phase is just shifted.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @MartinArgerami The complex part of the amplitude just encodes a phase shift

Comment: @BioPhysicist: saying so in your answer would improve it a lot.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Well, it's not my answer, but thanks!

Comment: @BioPhysicist:  my bad, I didn't notice it was not your answer. In any case, thanks for the clarification, which does answer the question for me.